# Error with rbindlist: Internal error: column 4 of result is determined to be integer64 but maxType=='character' != REALSXP

Tags: r, data.table, rbind

I have a large collection of .csv files (over 15,000) that I am trying to upload to R as a data frame. I have previously used this code successfully to upload similar .csv files, but for this current upload am encountering an error in the final step.

```
library(data.table)  
files <- list.files(path = "/Directory/", pattern = ".csv")
temp <- lapply(files, fread, sep=",")
Dataframe <- rbindlist(temp)
```

Error: Error in rbindlist(temp) :
Internal error: column 4 of result is determined to be integer64 but maxType=='character' != REALSXP

Can anyone help? Thanks!

Comment: You can read all the columns with `colClasses = "character"`

Comment: This is a `data.table` bug, can you please [file an issue](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues)? Please also run `table(sapply(temp, function(x) typeof(x[[4L])))`

Comment: I think better than `colClasses='character'`, you could also try `classes = sapply(fread(files[1L], sep=','), class); temp = lapply(files, fread, sep=',', colClasses=classes)`

Comment: Thank you @MichaelChirico added in this code ```classes = sapply(fread(files[1L], sep=','), class); temp = lapply(files, fread, sep=',', colClasses=classes)``` and it has worked. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: @SimonCopland glad it could help. Please do still file an issue -- you shouldn't ever be seeing an `Internal error` so it means we did something wrong! Your contribution could help prevent future users from encountering such a confusing situation

Comment: And answer your own question, that it was a bug in `packageVersion(data.table)`, you filed a bug report, then accept your answer, and complete the virtuous Q/A circle, and increase your reputation besides.